# Name for parameter binding must not be null or empty! For named parameters you need to use @Param for query method parameters on Java versions

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

This has been posted before but my issue is a little different. This is the JPQL query in question:

```
@Query("SELECT NEW com.htd.domain.ShopOrder(po.id, po.po_number, "
            + "po.due_date, po_part.id, po_part.part_quantity, "
            + "part.id, part.part_number, part.part_description, "
            + "part.plasma_hrs_per_part, part.grind_hrs_per_part, "
            + "part.mill_hrs_per_part, part.brakepress_hrs_per_part) "
            + "FROM Po po "
            + "LEFT JOIN po.partList po_part "
            + "LEFT JOIN po_part.part part "
            + "LEFT JOIN po_part.part where po.id = :id")
    List<ShopOrder> getShopOrder(long id);
```

Now I did try to do:

```
@Query("SELECT NEW com.htd.domain.ShopOrder(po.id, po.po_number, "
            + "po.due_date, po_part.id, po_part.part_quantity, "
            + "part.id, part.part_number, part.part_description, "
            + "part.plasma_hrs_per_part, part.grind_hrs_per_part, "
            + "part.mill_hrs_per_part, part.brakepress_hrs_per_part) "
            + "FROM Po po "
            + "LEFT JOIN po.partList po_part "
            + "LEFT JOIN po_part.part part "
            + "LEFT JOIN po_part.part where po.id = :id")
    List<ShopOrder> getShopOrder(@Param(value="id"));
```

But this giving me a warning saying:

```
    [ERROR] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/].  
 [dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in 
 context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested   
 exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: 
 Name for parameter binding must not be null or empty! For named parameters 
 you need to use @Param for query method parameters on Java versions < 8.; 
 nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Name for parameter 
 binding must not be null or empty! For named parameters you need to use 
 @Param for query method parameters on Java versions < 8.] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Name for parameter binding must not be 
null or empty! For named parameters you need to use @Param for query method   
parameters on Java versions < 8.
```

The method that is executing the query is:

```
 /**
     * Generate Shop Orders.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/generateShopOrder/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @Timed
    public void generate(@PathVariable Long id) throws URISyntaxException {
        System.out.println("po id to generate = " + id);

        List<ShopOrder> shopOrders = po_partRepository.getShopOrder(id);

        for(ShopOrder order: shopOrders) {
            System.out.println("-------Printing Shop Orders" + order);
        }

    }
```

Advice?

------------UPDATE----------------

This seemed to fix the issue:

```
@Query("SELECT NEW com.htd.domain.ShopOrder(po.id, po.po_number, "
            + "po.due_date, po_part.id, po_part.part_quantity, "
            + "part.id, part.part_number, part.part_description, "
            + "part.plasma_hrs_per_part, part.grind_hrs_per_part, "
            + "part.mill_hrs_per_part, part.brakepress_hrs_per_part) "
            + "FROM Po po "
            + "LEFT JOIN po.partList po_part "
            + "LEFT JOIN po_part.part part "
            + "LEFT JOIN po_part.part where po.id = ?1")
    List<ShopOrder> getShopOrder(Long id);
```

However now I am getting an error saying:

```
[ERROR] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/].
[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in 
context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested 
exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: 
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not instantiate class 
[com.htd.domain.ShopOrder] from tuple; nested exception is 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not 
instantiate class [com.htd.domain.ShopOrder] from tuple] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null
```

ShopOrder:

```
public ShopOrder(long po_id, String po_number, LocalDate po_due_date,
    long po_part_id, int part_quantity, long part_id,
    String part_number, String part_decription, BigDecimal plasma_hrs,
    BigDecimal grind_hours, BigDecimal mill_hrs,
    BigDecimal breakpress_hrs) {

        this.po_id = po_id;
        this.po_number = po_number;
        this.po_due_date = po_due_date;
        this.po_part_id = po_part_id;
        this.part_quantity = part_quantity;
        this.part_id = part_id;
        this.part_number = part_number;
        this.part_decription = part_decription;
        this.plasma_hrs = plasma_hrs;
        this.grind_hours = grind_hours;
        this.mill_hrs = mill_hrs;
        this.breakpress_hrs = breakpress_hrs;

    }
```

[image: Database tables]

Comment: WHAT gives you the error? What throws the exception? stack trace?

Comment: @NeilStockton answer updated with full stack trace

Comment: so perhaps there is no such constructor for ShopOrder ... check the types

Comment: @NeilStockton no there is (just added it) but I am beginning to thing the 'new' in my Query is not doing what I think it is. I thought it would create a new instance of ShopOrder. Am I correct?

Comment: what do you mean "new instance" ? You do a query and it will create an object and return it to you (assuming the constructor exists)

Comment: @NeilStockton yes that is want I assumed and I do have a constructor which I have posted.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Instead of using : po.id = :id just use ?1....

```
@Query("SELECT NEW com.htd.domain.ShopOrder(po.id, po.po_number, "
             + "po.due_date, po_part.id, po_part.part_quantity, "
            + "part.id, part.part_number, part.part_description, "
            + "part.plasma_hrs_per_part, part.grind_hrs_per_part, "
            + "part.mill_hrs_per_part, part.brakepress_hrs_per_part) "
            + "FROM Po po "
            + "LEFT JOIN po.partList po_part "
            + "LEFT JOIN po_part.part part "
            + "LEFT JOIN po_part.part where po.id = ?1")
    List<ShopOrder> getShopOrder(Long id);
```

Comment: That's correct, also mentioned on their official website :
Link - https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query

Comment: or else po.id = :id

Answer (score 85):

Try this parameter description:

```
List<ShopOrder> getShopOrder(@Param("id") long id);
```

Comment: I find it weird that JPA doesn't allow @Param tag without a value to use the same default param name as the variable name.

Comment: @AmrinderArora Because variable name is not accessible

Comment: @er-han Yes, but it certainly _can_ be.  For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40526925/why-are-spring-data-repository-method-parameters-names-not-available-even-on-jav?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @AmrinderArora yes, indeed. Thank you for this example. You are right, it can be done with '-parameters' compiler flag. I've found this: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.named-parameters

Comment: @AmrinderArora You are right, -parameters can solve the problem too.

Answer (score 0):

When running locally, comment out this in pom and rebuild maven project and then run the application.

```
    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency> -->
```